# magento 2.4.2 shows /index of instead of site

Tags: magento2

magento fresh install shows index of instead of site.
Os : ubuntu 20.04
php:7.4

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: after your url add pub path like :- localhost/urlname/pub/

Comment: From Magento 2.4.2 need to setup virtual host.

Comment: is virtual host neccessary

Comment: already tried using pub path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer in apche configuration file need to give `allowoveride all` for the document directory